# How to make a button open a specific .csv file using Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, csv, tkinter

I'm trying to get this program to print the contents of a `.csv` file onto a `GUI`.

I've created in `Tkinter`. It mostly works, but I can't figure out a way to get each button to print the contents of the file it's linked to.

At the moment I've created a variable that links to just one of the files, which shows that it works.

The variable is **"loadFiles"**, and the project it's set to open is "a_P.csv". Is there any way I can make the buttons link this variable to the relevant .csv file?

The code is in this pastebin `link: http://pastebin.com/ZP2pPvKA`

The program searches for files ending in `"_P.csv"` in the same folder as it, so you may have to create a .csv with 7 objects in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tried this the way heinzderaugust suggested at first:

```
 button[i] = ttk.Button(loadProject, text=data_files[i], command = lambda i=data_files[i]:load(i)).grid(column=1, row=i, sticky=W)
```

I was also able to solve this by using a class as the intermediary part of the callback:
(This class was inserted inside viewProject )

```
class Command:
            def __init__(self, callback, *args, **kwargs):
                    self.callback = callback
                    self.args = args
                    self.kwargs = kwargs

            def __call__(self):
                    return(self.callback(*self.args, **self.kwargs))
```

Then I changed your button definition to:

```
button[i] = ttk.Button(loadProject, text=data_files[i], command = Command(load,data_files[i])).grid(column=1, row=i, sticky=W)
```

And finally I changed the load function to accept a argument:

```
def load(myFile):                
            spamReader = csv.reader(open(myFile))
            for row in spamReader:
                    a = list(row)

            ttk.Label(loadProject, text=(a[0])).grid(column=4, row=0, sticky=W)
            ttk.Label(loadProject, text=("\n"+a[1])).grid(column=4, row=1, sticky=W)
            ttk.Label(loadProject, text=("\n"+a[2])).grid(column=4, row=2, sticky=W)
            ttk.Label(loadProject, text=(a[3])).grid(column=4, row=3, sticky=W)
            ttk.Label(loadProject, text=(a[4])).grid(column=4, row=4, sticky=W)
            ttk.Label(loadProject, text=("\n"+a[5])).grid(column=4, row=5, sticky=W)
            ttk.Label(loadProject, text=("\n"+a[6])).grid(column=4, row=6, sticky=W)
            ttk.Label(loadProject, text=("\n\n"+a[7])).grid(column=4, row=7, sticky=W)
```

I am unsure which would be best practice, but both do work.
(Certainly the lambda approach does sort of seem more 'pythonic')
Source: https://code.activestate.com/recipes/66521-avoiding-lambda-in-writing-callback-functions/

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working now. I went with the second one because it seems a bit easier to understand for me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a lambda function in order to pass an argument to your load function. Unfortunately pastebin ist down right now so i cannot have a look at your code. The idea is something like this:

for filename in filenames:
    ...Button(...,command=lambda i=filename:loadFile(i),...

so in your loadFile function you have the filename as first parameter